# Locus of Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers

Would be great to get your help in finding the locus of this complex number $z$:  $|z-z_1|+\sin \alpha|z-z_2|=\sin \theta$

From this question I proceed to a refined one-
What would **$$|z-z_1|+2|z-z_2|=k$$**
represent?

Comment: I substituted z and expanded taking squares of both sides but it turned into an ugly expression with a square root term which i cannot get rid of...

Comment: Just to be clear, you seem to be assuming that $a$ and $b$ are real.  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @mweiss no, sorry it was a blunder on my part... i would immediately correct it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.  If $\alpha = \pi / 2$, then this equation says that the sum of the distances from $z$ to $z_1$ and $z_2$ is a fixed constant -- i.e. $z$ is on an ellipse with foci at $z_1$ and $z_2$.  What happens if $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha = \pi$?  Can you generalize?

Comment: Thanks... this intuitive approach is what I was looking for. I can see it would represent a circle, ellipse and hyperbola for 0, 1 and -1 as values of $\sin\alpha$ but what about the intermediary values of $\sin\alpha$?